# unknown error in R during classification commands

Tags: r, dataframe, syntax-error

i have  letterdata.csv data and  i would like to apply   classification  task to this data, for this one i have read file in R

```
letters <- read.csv("letterdata.csv")
```

after that i have created test  and train data

```
> letters_train <- letters[1:16000, ]
> letters_test <- letters[16001:20000, ]
```

and then apply   kernel classification function

```
> letter_classifier <- ksvm(letter ~ ., data = letters_train,
+                           kernel = "vanilladot")
```

but it gives me  following error

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'letter' not found
```

i am using book and this command was in book, so i  decided  that, instead of letter, letters should be so  i apply following command

```
> letter_classifier <- ksvm(letters ~ ., data = letters_train,
+                           kernel = "vanilladot")
```

but it gives me another error

```
Error in model.frame.default(data = ..1, formula = x) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'letters'
>
```

so what can i do?

EDIT : structure of dataset

```
> str(letters)
'data.frame':   400375 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ X..DOCTYPE.html.: Factor w/ 40331 levels "  ","    ","      ",..: 40294 40203 40171 40212 40207 40208 40209 40210 40211 40213 ...
```

and about library i am using kernlab package

Comment: Avoid names like `letters`. There's already a built-in "dataset" named `letters`. Add `str(letters)` and `dput(head(letters,20))` to your question plus packages you're using.

Comment: i have updated  information

Comment: i have changed  name for myletter, but the same error : invalid type list for  myletter

Comment: Please edit to add the output of `dput(head(letters,20))` so people can help.

Comment: but it gives me huge result

Comment: how can i post  whole result? it gives me huge  text messages,  huge description

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to help further. Maybe someone else can better guide. In the meantime, you could find some tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Looks like your data isn't a CSV... could you post the first few rows of your file `letterdata.csv`? How many columns do you expect it to have? How many rows? From your `str(letters)` it looks like it has 400,375 rows and 1 column. From the code above it looks like you think it has 20,000 rows and multiple columns.

Comment: here is  datasets  https://github.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets, look please at letterdata.csv  file

Comment: How did you download the file? Seems like maybe you saved the HTML Github page? That would explain the `X..DOCTYPE.html` in your `str`. I would recommend either (a) cloning the repository to get the file or (b) if you want to save it from the web, go to the file's page on Github but **click the `Raw` button before saving**. You want to save the raw CSV file, not wrapped in HTML for web display.

Comment: In the future, I'd strongly recommend doing a quick check to make sure data imported correctly before moving on to modeling. Just glance at `head(your_data)` and make sure it looks like it has the rows and columns you expect.

Answer (score 0):

R is automaticly saving your data as a list, you need to convert all your data into a data frame.

```
df <- as.data.frame(letters)
df_train <- as.data.frame(letters_train) -- this is where the error must be coming from
```

Then just use df instead:

```
letter_classifier <- ksvm(df ~ ., data = df_train,
+                           kernel = "vanilladot")
```

Comment: This is better left as a comment not an answer.

Comment: Well, I wanted to comment but can't because reputation minimum and I prefer to have an incomplete answer and then complete it, then not help.

Comment: @datodatuashvili I think this should help you now

Comment: I still don't think this answer is useful. OP posted `str(letters)
'data.frame':   400375 obs. of  1 variable:` in the question showing that `letters` is a data frame, so using `as.data.frame` on it will do nothing. I'm not sure where you get the idea that it is a `list` (or that OP saved it in R). Also as it has one column not named `df`, the formula `df ~ .` will be an error.

Comment: I appreciate that you want to help immediately, but perhaps look for clearer questions until you have enough rep to comment and request clarification. It only takes 50 rep to comment anywhere, so you're quite close.

Comment: Yes, but the letters_train might not be, like I said in the answer, that's where it must be coming from.
Because even if you take part of a dataframe it can be converted to a list, since it has 1 variable, the first one was just a too make sure :)

Comment: > letter_classifier <- ksvm(df ~ ., data = df_train,
+                           kernel = "vanilladot")
Error in model.frame.default(data = ..1, formula = x) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'df'
>   the same error

Comment: *"that's where it must be coming from"*. Strongly disagree.